# Passing variable in airflow macros

Tags: python, variables, macros, airflow

Please help me with
`{{ execution_date.subtract(hours = 5) }}`
Here instead of hardcoding 5, I want to pass it as a variable.
I am not able to find a way to pass a variable and finally use the value of the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
f'echo {{{{ execution_date.subtract(hours = {value}) }}}}'
```

Example with BashOperator:

```
value = 5 # This can be set dynamically
hello_my_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    bash_command=f'echo {{{{ execution_date.subtract(hours = {value}) }}}}',
    dag=dag,
)
```

[image]